# Show/hide onClick JQuery

Tags: jquery, css

I want to show/hide text which is `display: none;` on CSS once the button is clicked and clear the input field on onClick function. Now the text is still shown once its already display. Thank you for your help.

```js
$('#submit').click(function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    str = $('#string').val();

    if (checkPalin(str)) {
        return $('#true').css('display', 'block');
    } else {
        return $('#false').css('display', 'block');
    }
});
```

```css
#result span {
    display: none;
    font-weight: bold;
}
```

```html
<input type="text" name="string" id="string" value="check">
<input id="submit" type="submit" value="check">
<p id="result">
    <span id="true">This string is a padindrome!</span>
    <span id="false">This string is
        <strong>not</strong> a padindrome
    </span>
</p>
```

Comment: _"once the button is clicked"_ What button?

Comment: Hi @Krittiya Clark, your question was not clear

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try:

```
$('#submit').click(function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    str = $('#testString').val();
    // Console logging
    console.log('The value entered was: ' + str);
    if (checkPalin(str)) {
        // Clear the value of #testString
        $('#testString').val('');
        // Display the #true result
        $('#true').show();
        // Hide the #false result
        $('#false').hide();
        // Console logging
        console.log('The value ' + str + ' passed our condition');
    } else {
        // Clear the value of #testString
        $('#testString').val('');
        // Display the #false result
        $('#false').show();
        // Hide the #true result
        $('#true').hide();
        // Console logging
        console.log('The value ' + str + ' failed our condition');
    }
    return false;
});
```

You'll essentially be checking the condition as you were, except you'll be using the Hide() and Show() methods to display your results as needed.

Comment: It works only first click and the text still displays, not remove from the DOM. Both texts displays side by side.